# Why does create-react-app initialize twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've initialize a react app using `npx create-react-app`:

```
import React from 'react';

class Expensive {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructing expensive class');
  }
}

function App() {
  const expensiveRef = React.useRef(new Expensive());
  return (
    <div className="App">
      app
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, I am seeing that `constructing expensive class` is printed to the console twice. Why is this?

I get the same result if I replace

`const expensiveRef = React.useRef(new Expensive());`

with

`const [expensiveState, setExpensiveState] = React.useState(new Expensive());`

Comment: This is an interesting question in it's own right, but why not just instantiate it outside the app component if you only want a Singleton?

Comment: For classical component, it runs first to check diff, then once more to render, you can find related info in the official document

Comment: @JaredSmith I am considering it, but I have a use case where <App> re-renders with new data thus requiring a re-initialization of `Expensive`. In that case I suppose it would be possible to overwrite the original `Expensive` instance from within useEffect?

Comment: How expensive is it really? Have you profiled and found that your app is hiccuping in that constructor?

Comment: @JaredSmith It's a bit complicated, but I'm using a similar pattern over at soundscape.world. In that case, I'm create WebAudio nodes as refs. However, they're being re-initialized and garbage collected, leading to poor performance over long durations.

Comment: @mracette again, do you *know* that from profiling, or are you *guessing* that's what's causing your perf issues?

Comment: @JaredSmith extensive profiling

Comment: In that case yeah, maybe create a state with a condition for the re-initialization x, a lazy initialized state with the webaudio node y, and a useEffect with a dependency on x that updates y. It's a bit hairy but not too too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every code is executed on every render that's why it is logged multiple times, even useState will remember the first instance.

If you want it to be initialized only once, use that useState version like this

```js
const [expensiveState, setExpensiveState] = React.useState(() => new Expensive());
```

So you pass **function** instead of **object initialization**

see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: This answer the correct way to fix OP's problem, and I upvoted, but the last line is wrong. That is *exactly* what `useRef` is for. From the official docs, emphasis mine: "useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will *persist for the full lifetime of the component.*" It's not just for DOM references.

Comment: Thanks. Lazy initialization leads to the behavior I expected initially, but I am still struggling to understand why the constructor would be executed on every render without it.

I also found that I can use lazy initialization in a ref like this:
`const expensiveRef = React.useRef((() => new Expensive())());`

Comment: Its kinda hard for me to explain it other way, but i am happy that it works @mracette

Comment: @Tonoslav would you at least be able to explain why <App> re-renders at all when there is no state change after the initialization?

Comment: @mracette not 100% sure when I don't see the whole codebase , maybe because of initializing of that ref